# troubles deploying with diigtal ocean node sequelize

Tags: node.js, deployment, digital-ocean, sequelize-cli

Im trying to make a deploy in Digital Ocean when i try to make a migration using sequelize cli but wehn i do it

```
npx sequelize db:migrate
```

its says a error in the terminal and says

```
ERROR: Cannot find "/home/deploy/app/config/config.json". Have you run "sequelize init"?
```

then i tri using

```
npx sequelize init
```

and create all the folders (migrations - models - config - seeders, etc) THEN i move my migrations to the folder created to try to fix the issue, then in the config/config.json y config all the bd config, and try it again but says the same issue all the time

how can i fix that please i need to make this deploy can someone helps me?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using

```
npx sequelize db:migrate WORKDIR /myapp/path
```